# cascading dropdown using data in the same table in dataverse for model driven app

Tags: cascading, dataverse

In Dataverse, I have a school table with the following columns:

### School        Teacher    Grade

School1      Teacher1     4
School1      Teacher2     5
School2      Teacher3     4
School2      Teacher4     5

I want to create another table (form 1) where I would like to bring all these details using lookup as below:

### FormName      School                                       Teacher

XYZ          School1(lookup school table and select)   Teacher2 (lookup school table and select)

but I am unable to do this in Model Driven App.  I tried using lookup as above, but it gave School Name for both school and teacher.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The req you wish to achieve and your implementation is not the correct way. When you do a lookup (in background relationship with school Table) you do either 1:N or N:1 in your case it is N:1 (school Teacher:School) it will refer to a record and will show primary name of record (in your case school name).

your requirement can be achieved by creating just one lookup to School but adding filter criteria to lookup so that it will show you only those records that match school name and Teacher.

Now when you select such lookup it will show Primary Name of school record(school name).

There is feature is Model driven App called [quick view form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/create-edit-quick-view-forms?view=op-9-1), this will show all the details of School Table Record.

[Additional article for ref](https://www.marksgroup.net/blog/dynamics-365-quick-view-forms/)